# Avoiding non breaking space using NumberFormatter

Tags: swift, number-formatting, nsnumberformatter

I have a `NumberFormatter` setup like the following:

```
let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
currencyFormatter.groupingSeparator = "."
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
currencyFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "it_IT")
currencyFormatter.currencySymbol = ""
```

I need to retrieve a value based on a string value as input.

```
currencyFormatter.number(from: "1.000,00") // nil
currencyFormatter.number(from: "1.000,00\u{00a0}") // 1000
```

In the first sample, the formatter returns `nil`, while in the second I obtain the correct value (`\u{00a0}` is the non breaking space symbol).

Is there a way to make the first sample working without adding the space symbol?

Comment: Makes no sense. You refer to two different formatters, `currencyFormatter` and `formatter`.

Comment: @matt my mistake on writing the question. fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no currency symbol, this number formatter's style needs to be `.decimal`, not `.currency`. This is sufficient:

```
let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
currencyFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "it_IT")
```

Comment: Indeed, if you say `.currency`, the formatter becomes _very_ picky about what it will accept (as you've already discovered). It expects a space followed by a Euro sign, and nothing else will do. I don't know why the nonbreaking space subverts that. But the point is, if you say `.decimal`,  both of your inputs work.